# ld: library not found for -ldflags

Tags: go

Having issue on MAC

ld: library not found for -ldflags
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am trying to run this

```
args = -ldflags "-X '$(version).VERSION=$(bin-version)' -X '$(version).GITHUB_SHA=$(sha)'"
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build $(args) -o ./bin/$(call bin_name,$@) ./cmd/$(call bin_name,$@)
```

Tried to follow this: https://cydiageeks.com/fix-ld-library-not-found-xcode/ still couldn't able to fix it.

Also uninstalled and installed golang. Current version go1.19.5